# Why does the map method for the List class in flutter not work anymore?

Tags: list, flutter, methods

I opened my project one day and multiple files had errors were there were none before. All of the errors were due to the map method for the list class.

The error says: "The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'List'."

If there is no way of getting the map method to work, how should I work around this issue?

Code Snippet:

```
    // User list from snapshot
      List<TestUser> _userListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
          return TestUser(
            name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '', 
            year: doc.data()['year'] ?? 0,
            school: doc.data()['school'] ?? 'School',
          );
        }).toList();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add object type

```
 return snapshot.docs.map<TestUser>((doc){
```

Comment: I tried to add the object type, and I am still running into the same issue :(